Parameter tab is disabled for Controllers
for me i'm facing some issues like Parameter tab is disabled for Logic Controllers.
If i need to use interleave controller, there i have to go with multiple samplers with different parameters there i am unable to move to parameters tab. So i couldn't use multiple samplers.
Parameter disabled
I tried:
I have created a test plan for Flight booking Scenario.

Login
Flight reservation
Confirmation

I split the samplers with the above transaction controllers. I need to check the reservation functionality for 5 flights.For this scenario, Login and Confirmation pages are same. I need to work on Flight reservation. For that i have added a logic Controller between Login and Confirmation page named as interleave controller. I Copied Flight reservation samplers and pasted for 5 time and changed the name as flight reservation 1 to 5.
Actual:
Inside the Flight reservation 1. I was tried to change the Parameters. but the tab was not working.
Expected:
The parameters tab should be enabled. And i should be able to enter different parameter like Departure and Destination fields for all the flight reservation 1-5.

If you have anything in the "Body Data" tab of the HTTP Request sampler - you won't be able to switch to "Parameters" tab (and vice versa)
If you cannot figure out what part of the JSON payload is responsible for departure/destination - re-record your test script once again using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder or JMeter Chrome Extension and compare the resulting scripts. The values which will be different should be responsible for departure/destination
